# How to increase number or age of playback position files remembered in VLC?

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player

VLC remembers the playback position of most media files (see [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177589/vlc-player-does-not-remember-last-played-position) to enable in macOS). For some media I have played a long time ago, VLC does not remember the playback position and starts at the beginning.

How can I remember the playback position of more files, or of older files, or of all files unless they are played to the end?

Answer (score 1):

#### VLC may not remember the playback position of all files and starts at the beginning.

You might try the [Moments' Tracker](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154020/) VLC add-on:

> Moments' Tracker allows you to track all your favorite movie/media
> moments and scenes. Bookmark your favorite moment, give it a
> title/caption, and that's it.
>
> Once you've done this, you can jump directly to your moment anytime
> you open that media file, no need to scroll through trying to find
> certain moment.
>
> If you just want to mark your position so that you could resume from
> where you stopped, you could use the "Checkpoint" feature.
>
> Click the "Checkpoint!" button, and retrieve it whenever you want
> using "Retrieve Checkpoint" button.
>
> Whenever you open a media file, all your bookmarked moments are
> displayed so that you can manipulate it.

<sup>Caveat: I haven't tested it yet.</sup>

Drawback:

> Unfortunately you have to remember to manually save your last play location, but I'm not sure if there's a way around that with the current LUA APIs.

Source [Moments' Tracker - addons.videolan.org](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154020/)

Comment: Not old ones as you point out in your question. Or more than a certain number of files ... that's why the add-on is useful as a workaround ...

Comment: This isn't very convenient though (or at least not more convenient than what I already do now, which is to manually make a note somewhere in a text file).